# Достать часть ссылки с помощью regexp

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как с помощью Регулярных выражений достать id таблицы гугл (Ссылка формата: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jg2vgmdz123ZJKy9J3eqBdFseH4FmpzmmhrVe8/edit#gid=732150832)?
Нужно достать 1jg2vgmdz123ZJKy9J3eqBdFseH4FmpzmmhrVe8

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать это Lookahead [выражение](https://regex101.com/r/yb6hhq/1):

```
([^/]+)(?=/edit)
```

Оно захватывает группу символов следом за которыми идет /edit